# Specify ParentId for "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource" in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

How to specify ParentId of existing "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi" for "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource" in CloudFormation template? For example, I have already created API Gateway REST API and I want to specify it in my template:

```
 MyTestResource:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: 'RestApi'
      ParentId: <<placeholder_for_my_value>>
```

In case when I describe "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi" in my template too I can do that such way:

```
  ParentId: !GetAtt "RestApi.RootResourceId"
```

But how can I do that for already existing REST API?

Comment: Is your already existing REST API in the same CloudFormation stack as `MyTestResource `?

Comment: Yes. In short, I need to add a new resourse to existing REST API using CloudFormation template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup the resource id of an existing REST API either through the console
Click "your REST API" -> "Resources"
in the higher left side you'll see something like

```
 APIs>YOUR_API_NAME (YOUT_API_ID)>Resources>/your_already_existing_resource (YOUR_RESOURCE_ID)
```

That's then the resource Id you can specify as a "parentId".
Alternatively, use the `aws` cli.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-resources.html

Where you'd need to specify the `rest-api-id` which you again can either get from the console, or via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-rest-apis.html

Comment: I tried to specify it as 'ParentId:"yilqa7oeyl"', where "yilqa7oeyl" was Id which I got according your method, but I got error message, that CloudFormation couldn't find it.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked...are you sure you are creating the CF template in the same region as the pre-existing resource?...

`
    ---
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Description: 'Testing passing exisiting resource id'

    Resources:
      MyTestResource:
          Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
           Properties:
               RestApiId: "rest-api-id-I-got-from-cli"
               ParentId: "resource-id-I-got-from-cli"
               PathPart: "blah"
`

Comment: I fixed that, it was my fault. All is fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, if you need to specify a new resource in an existing API, you can check the stack in the CloudFormation, in the resources tab and see the Logical Did with which the API was generated.

Whit that LogicalId you can specify en that manner, considering logical Id as ***RestApiLogicalId***:

```
 "ParentId": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [
            "RestApiLogicalId",
            "RootResourceId"
          ]
        }
```

Enjoy!